# How to allow submit until certain conditions are fulfilled in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel-5.8 application. In it, there are two models:

appraisal_respondents and hr_employees

```
class AppraisalRespondent extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'appraisal_respondents';

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
                'id',
                'employee_id',
                'respondent_id',
                'respondent_email',
                'is_submitted',
                'respondent_date',
            ];

  protected $dates = [
      'created_at'
  ];
  
  protected $casts = [];
  

  public function employeerespondent()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','respondent_id');
  }
  
  public function employee()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee','employee_id');
  }  

}


class HrEmployee extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'hr_employees';
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  protected $fillable = [
                'id',
                'employee_code',
                'email',
                'line_manager_id',
                'first_name',
                'first_name',
                'other_name',
            ];
  
  

  protected $appends = ['full_name'];
  
  public function linemanager()
  {
      return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee', 'employee_id', 'line_manager_id');
  }             
  
  public function fullName()
  {
      return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->other_name . ' ' . $this->last_name;
  }
  

  public function getFullNameAttribute()
  {
      return (String) $this->fullName();
  }
  
}
```

HrEmployee: An employee will only have one line_manager (self referencing - one-to-one) while a line manager will have one or more direct reports (employees attached to him - he is there line manager).

AppraisalRespondent: An employee will have more than one respondent (at least five - 5)

AppraisalRespondent is the main model

Controller

```
 public function submit_respondents(){

    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    

    
DB::beginTransaction(); 
    try {             
    $unapproved_post = AppraisalRespondent::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)
            ->update([
                'is_submitted' => 1,

    DB::commit();
        Session::flash('success', 'Respondents Submitted successfully');
        return redirect()->back();
     } catch (Exception $exception) {
         Log::error($exception);
DB::rollback();

            Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
            return redirect()->back();
    }           
}
```

I am using spatie for role and permission management

I have several roles (Super Admin, Admin, Line Manager and Employee), but I want to perform this action using two roles: 1. Line Manager  and Employee.

That is:

if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Line Manager'))  and  if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Employee'))

Each user will be allowed to submit minimum of five(5) respondents (This number excludes the initiator of the MSF i.e. if the initiator decides to select himself/herself as one of the respondents, then the minimum total number of respondents becomes 6).)

Note: Line Managers are also employees who have his own line Manager

How do I achieve these:

1. If logged in user is Line Manager:

a)  If none of the 5 respondents is his/her line manager, a prompt will be displayed notifying the employee to include his/her line manager.

b)  If three of the respondents are not his/her direct reports, a prompt will be displayed notifying the employee that he /she must select a minimum of three direct reports

NB: If the Line Manager doesn't have up to three(3) direct reports (employees under him), the application should allow it based on the number of direct reports under him.

2. If logged in user is Employee:

a) if none of the 5 respondents is his/her line manager, a prompt will be displayed notifying the employee to include his/her line manager

How do I achieve these?

Thanks

Comment: there are many ways to achieve this, if you want it server side, take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: @N69S - Please can you show me a sample?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_validation.htm